# Prevent Google Tag Manager from reading input-elements

Tags: javascript, forms, google-tag-manager

I'm implementing Google Tag Manager (GTM) on multiple web applications. One of these applications asks the user for personal information. There are good processes for auditing the application code, to make sure that the personal information is stored safely and does not leak.

However, implementing GTM will inevitably mean that the web analysts can write and deploy JavaScript code that reads these input-fields and sends the information to third-parties (such as Google Analytics).

Is there a way of preventing Google Tag Manager from being able to access the input fields where the user enters this information?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this with GTM v2, but in v1 you [can blacklist types of tags](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#security) via the code in your page (this cannot be overriden by configuration in the GTM interface) - so you can prevent users from implementing custom HTML/JavaScript Tags that may include code to extract information from the page. Remember to also blacklist custom JavaScript macros as they could do the same.

If your pages writes any information to global javascript variables you also have to disable the JavaScript variable macro (which would allow a user to write an extraction function in a macro), and possibly the DOM element macro

Better still, don't do blacklist, create a whitelist.

In addition while many people may have permissions to add tags there should be only one person with the right to publish changes who signs off every new Tag. That way there is at least somebody responsible if things go awry.